# Can I override or remove the "Alert preference"

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

Is it possible to remove the secondary account link for the "Alert preferences" or is it possible to override this in the link type options in the banno external application section?

[Alert preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGT92.png)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like there is a *link type* that would support doing that. The supported link types are documented in https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/getting-started/#alternatives-to-plugins.